# Matching a function pointer as template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get `accumulate2` template working, however it results in compilation errors.  I'm not sure why the compiler cannot match the lambda function to this template.  Does anyone know whats wrong and how to resolve it?  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<typename Iter, typename Val>
Val accumulate2(Iter first, Iter last, Val s, Val (*op)(Val&, Val&))
{
    while (first!=last) {
        s = op(s,*first);
        ++first;
    }
    return s;
}

template<typename Iter, typename Val, typename Oper>
Val accumulate(Iter first, Iter last, Val s, Oper op)
{
    while (first!=last) {
        s = op(s,*first);
        ++first;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    int v0 = accumulate(a, a+2, 0, [](int _v0, int _v1){return _v0 + _v1;});
    cout << v0 << endl;
    int v1 = accumulate2(a, a+2, 0, [](int _v0, int _v1){return _v0 + _v1;});
    cout << v1 << endl;
}
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall test166.cc && ./a.out
test166.cc:30:14: error: no matching function for call to 'accumulate2'
    int v1 = accumulate2(a, a+2, 0, [](int _v0, int _v1){return _v0 + _v1;});
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
test166.cc:6:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'Val (*)(Val &, Val &)' against '(lambda at test166.cc:30:37)'
Val accumulate2(Iter first, Iter last, Val s, Val (*op)(Val&, Val&))
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` is already not nice, but `using namespace std;` and using names from `std::` is worse. It is unlikely that `iostream` includes `algorithm`, but you never know..

Comment: @idclev463035818 thanks but that has nothing to do with the error

Comment: Template argument deduction does not use implicit conversion. Stateless lambda can be converted to function pointer, but it requires one implicit conversion. That is why your code fail. Try: `+[](int _v0, int _v1){return _v0 + _v1;}`, also signature should be: `Val (*op)(Val,Val)` - no references there. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/DSW26k)

Comment: @rafix07 That was it!  Thank you.  I need to find where the + to create stateful lambda is documented...

Comment: By `+` you are creating function pointer with signature `int(*)(int,int)` from your lambda.

Comment: Why would you want this? Your first version is a better general solution. If you need to extract the signature you can do that with type traits.

Comment: @super I'm using examples from Stroustrups book and testing them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the function signature required removal of references and lambda expression needs to be stateless to be a function pointer explicitly.  New working code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<typename Iter, typename Val>
Val accumulate2(Iter first, Iter last, Val s, Val (*op)(Val, Val))
{
    while (first!=last) {
        s = op(s,*first);
        ++first;
    }
    return s;
}

template<typename Iter, typename Val, typename Oper>
Val accumulate(Iter first, Iter last, Val s, Oper op)
{
    while (first!=last) {
        s = op(s,*first);
        ++first;
    }
    return s;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    int v0 = accumulate(a, a+2, 0, [](int _v0, int _v1){return _v0 + _v1;});
    cout << v0 << endl;
    int v1 = accumulate2(a, a+2, 0, &add);
    cout << v1 << endl;
    int v2 = accumulate2(a, a+2, 0, +[](int _v0, int _v1){return _v0 + _v1;});
    cout << v2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: "and lambda expression needs to be stateful"  I think you misunderstood the above comment. "Stateless lambda can be converted to function pointer,"  that refers to the fact that a lambda that captures something (ie a lambda that has state) **cannot** be converted to a function pointer. What you changed in your code is that `+` already triggers the conversion that is needed to make the overload a match